# $K$ field, $f/g\in K(X)-K$, $f,g\in K[X]$ coprime then $[K(X):K(f/g)]=\max(\deg f, \deg g)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> 1) Let $K$ be a field, $q=f/g\in K(X)-K$ with $f,g\in K[X]$ coprime. Show that $q$ is transcendental over $K$ and that $[K(X):K(q)]=\max(\deg f, \deg g)$. Calculate the minimal polynomial of $X$ over $K(q)$.

My approach: $0=\sum a_i(f/g)^i=\sum a_i g^{n-i}f^i/g^n\iff a:=\sum a_i g^{n-i}f^i=0$ but $\varphi(a)=a_nf^n=r\neq0$ where $\varphi:K[X]\rightarrow(K/(g))[X]$ canonical homomorphism and $a_nf^n=qg+r$ ($r\neq0$ because $f,g$ coprime and $a_n$ unit). So $f/g$ is transcendental over $K$.

Now for the dimension part I've tried to look at $\psi:K(q)[X]\rightarrow K(X), h\mapsto h(X)$. Now if I could calculate the minimal polynomial of $X$ and can show that the map is surjective I would be finished. But I can't quite see how the map is surjective and I can't think of the minimal polynomial!!! $h(X)=\sum_j(\sum_i a_{ij}(f/g)^i)X^i$. Is this correct till now? Is this the right way? Some tips and insights would be nice!

> 2) Let $a,b\in\mathbb C$, $m,n\in \mathbb N$ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$ and $a^m=2,b^n=3$ then $\mathbb Q(a,b)=\mathbb Q(ab)$ and calculate the minimal polynomial of $ab$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Now $(ab)^{mn}=(a^m)^n(b^n)^m=2^n3^m$ so $ab$ is root of $x^{mn}-2^n3^m$, so  $[\mathbb Q(ab):\mathbb Q]\leq mn$. Now $(ab)^n=3a^n$. So $a^n\in\mathbb Q(ab)$ and so is $(a^n)^x/2^y=(a^n)^x/(a^m)^y=a^{nx-ym}$, and as $m,n$ are coprime $a\in\mathbb Q(ab)$. So is $b$. So $\mathbb Q(a,b)=\mathbb Q(ab)$.  $x^{mn}-2^n3^m$ is also the minimal polynomial because $[\mathbb Q(a):\mathbb Q]=m, [\mathbb Q(b):\mathbb Q]=n$,so $n,m|[\mathbb Q(ab):\mathbb Q]$ so $[\mathbb Q(ab):\mathbb Q]=nm$. Is there an argument to show $[\mathbb Q(ab):\mathbb Q]= mn$ immediately (i.e. show its irreducibility)?

Comment: Well done for showing your working! However, in future, please ask one question at a time! :)

Comment: So I've got the homomorphism $\psi:K(q)[Y]\rightarrow K(X),h\mapsto h(X)$.Now $k:=f(Y)-(f(X)/g(X))g(Y)$ is in the kernel of $\psi$. Now $k$ is irreducible as $k=-(f(X)/g(X))g(Y)+f(Y)\in(K[Y])[q]$ is linear and $f,g$ coprime (as if it would factor, then into degree $0$, which is a polynomial in $Y$, and $1$ polynomials). So it is the minimal polynial of $X$ over $K(q)$. The degree of $k$ is $\max(m, n)$ with $\deg f=m, \deg g = n$ which is clear if $m\neq n$, if $m=n$ then the highest coefficient of $k$ is $f_n+g_n(f(X)/g(X))\neq 0$ as $f_n\in K$, $g_n(f(X)/g(X))\in K(q)-K$.

Comment: So now I can argue $X\in im( \psi$) and $im( \psi)\cong K(q)[Y]/(k)$, so its a field containing $X$ so $im(\psi)=K(X)$ (as $im(\psi)\subset K(X)$

Comment: Still need help with 2) to show directly that the polynomial is irreducible!