# Solving $u(f,g)/v(f,g)=f'$, where $f,g \in k[t]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, field-theory

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $f=f(t),g=g(t) \in k[t]$.
Denote $f'=f'(t)$ the derivative of $f$.
Let $u=u(x,y),v=v(x,y) \in k[x,y]$, with $v \neq 0$, and $u,v$ coprime in $k[x,y]$. (I do not mind to further assume that $k \in \{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$, if this simplifies the answer).

> Is it possible to find a general solution to $u(f,g)/v(f,g)=f'$?

Although $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are assumed to be coprime in $k[x,y]$, it may happen (or it must happen?) that $u(f(t),g(t))$ and $v(f(t),g(t))$ are *not* coprime in $k[t]$; for example, $u(x,y)=2y, v(x,y)=x, f(t)=t^2, g(t)=t^3$.

Ways for solution: **(1)** Integrate both sides, but I do not know what the result on the left side should be. **(2)** Differentiate both sides:
Then I guess we should apply the chain rule, but still I am not sure I know how to solve the new equation. **(3)** Perhaps some considerations of degrees are relevant here (perhaps no). **(4)** I thought that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109087/k-field-f-g-in-kx-k-f-g-in-kx-coprime-then-kxkf-g-max-deg) question is relevant, but now I see that it may not be relevant, since here $u(f(t),g(t))$ and $v(f(t),g(t))$ are probably *not* coprime in $k[t]$.

**Example:** $f(t)=t^6+t^2$, $g(t)=t^3$. We have, $\frac {g}{f-g^2}= \frac{t^3}{t^6+t^2-t^6}= \frac{t^3}{t^2}=t$. Therefore, $g'(t)=3t^2=3(\frac {g}{f-g^2})^2$ and
$f'(t)=6t^5+2t=6(\frac {g}{f-g^2})^5+2(\frac {g}{f-g^2})$. 
I do not understand how the below answer helps in such cases.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Do you understand that this question asks you to show: There is no rational functional way to shortcut computing derivatives by limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  $g$ is completely unconstrained.  What happens to the degrees when we take $g = 0$? or $g = f$?

> Further hint:  $g = 0$: $\deg_x u(x,y) \deg_t f = (\deg_t(f) - 1) + \deg_x v(x,y) \deg_t f$.  Look at this equation modulo $\deg_t f \geq 2$ to determine that $\deg_t f$ is *very* constrained.  So a general solution is out.  I might also mention that the cases where a solution is possible are constrained away as well by conditions on $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Thank you for your hints! What if we further assume that the degree of $g$ is $\leq $ the degree of $f$ (or vice versa).

Comment: You have difficulties getting constraints if $\deg_t f = 1 + \deg_t g$ or if $\deg_t f = -1 + \deg_t g$, since these are the degrees needed to hit the degree of $f'$.

Comment: Please, can you elaborate (perhaps in an answer)?

Comment: Also, why do you need more information?

Comment: You already know $f$ must be linear or constant...

Comment: Sorry, I had problems seeing your answer (the four lines were blank). I will now read it and comment

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure I fully understand your answer. Please, could you explain why $f$ must be linear or constant? Did you mean in the special case $g=0$? But what if $g \neq 0$?

Comment: $g = 0$: $(\deg_x u(x,y) -1 -\deg_x v(x,y)) \deg_t f =  - 1$. Then $\deg_t f \geq 2$ is impossible (we are dealing with integers), so necessarily $\deg_ f  \in \{0,1\}$. I will try to see what happens for $g \neq 0$.

Comment: $g$ is *unconstrained*.  This has to work for *every possible choice of $g$*, including $g = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I really apologize for asking you again, but I do not understand; do you claim in your above answer that $\deg{f} \in \{0,1\}$ also for arbitrary $g$? (please see the example I have added later). I guess you probably meant something else, unfortunately I do not understand what it is exactly.

Comment: $\forall f,g, u(f,g)/v(f,g) = f'$ includes $\forall f, u(f,0)/v(f,0) = f'$, which *forces* $\deg_t f \in \{0,1\}$.  This is already a sufficient contradiction.

Comment: Oh, only now I understand what you meant. Sorry, it was my mistake for not explaining myself clearly. I meant something else.. I meant to ask: if for a given pair $f,g$, one can find $u$ such that $u(f,g)/v(f,g)=f'$, then what should be $f,g$? But now I think/guess that my question does not have a complete answer. A special case is when $k(g,f)=k(t)$ as in my example. Thank you very much for trying to help.

Comment: And characterizing $f,g$ such that $k(f,g)=k(t)$ can be done by using D-resultants: $k(f,g)=k(t)$ if and only if their D-resultant is non-zero. (There are several papers in this spirit).

Comment: When I asked my question I hoped that I was missing something trivial concerning derivatives/integrals. I wish there was something trivial that could help.